# Thymeleaf cannot get list in an object

Tags: java, thymeleaf

The following html piece using Thymeleaf template engine, does not work as I expect it to. ${value} does not print the string value in the list named rowList, instead it prints : `...api.model.Row@46b222d` .

```
<tr class="theRow" th:each="row : ${valuesPerRow}">


       <td th:each="value : ${row.rowList}">
               <span th:text="${value}"></span>
       </td>
</tr>
```

valuesPerRow is `List<Row>`

Row :

```
public class Row {
    private List<String> rowList;
    private String uniqueId;

    public Row(List<String> rowList, String uniqueId) {
        this.rowList = rowList;
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public List<String> getRowList() {
        return rowList;
    }

    public void setRowList(List<String> rowList) {
        this.rowList = rowList;
    }

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }
}
```

What do you think could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a problem in one of my methods, and I gave the wrong view name, so my changes did not work.

For anyone viewing this question, the code above works. You can do that obviously.

Thanks for anyone who gave a thought on this.

Comment: You should probably override toString() anyway - it's a good habit in general